# Rewriting blocks in admin

Tags: magento2, blocks, di.xml

**di.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Amasty\Reports\Block\Adminhtml\Navigation" type="Shop\Reports\Block\Adminhtml\Navigation" />
</config>
```

**Block class:**

```
<?php

namespace Shop\Reports\Block\Adminhtml;

class Navigation extends \Amasty\Reports\Block\Adminhtml\Navigation
{
    public function getConfig()
    {
    }
}
```

I'm trying to rewrite `\Amasty\Reports\Block\Adminhtml\Navigation::getConfig` method. However the original method is called when the page is loaded. When I try to rewrite other methods, they are rewritten successfully. What can be the cause of this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Simple things to check first (you probably will have done all of these!)

- Make sure your module is enabled and you've run setup:upgrade after enabling
- clear the magento cache (bin/magento cache:flush)
- recompile di if in production mode (bin/magento setup:di:compile)

If those don't resolve the issue, then my next question would be:

What is the access level of the function you are trying to overwrite? (public / protected / private)?

If it is public, it should work, but you could consider using a plugin instead: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

It's less intrusive than overriding a whole class, and using the "around" plugin type, you can override the function.

If however, the access level is protected / private, then you'll need to override a function that calls the getConfig function as well, because php classes will use the parent class context when calling a private function (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756609/strange-behavior-when-overriding-private-methods for a better explanation)

Hope this helps! :)